# Screenshot routine gives a blank image with LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a screenshot saver routines. I'm using the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Screenshots) as a base, so the resulting code is like this:

```
public void update(float deltaTime) {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) {
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.F10)) {
            this.saveScreenshot(new FileHandle(new File("screenshots/screenShot001.png")));
        }
    }

    public void saveScreenshot(FileHandle file) {
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

        PixmapIO.writePNG(file, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }

    public Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean flipY) {
        Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL10.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        final Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(w, h, Format.RGBA8888);
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        final int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        if (flipY) {
            final int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
                pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
            }
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.put(lines);
        } else {
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.get(lines);
        }

        return pixmap;
    }
```

The file is created and it seems to be a correct PNG image with a correct size but it is a blank one. The application is the sample that setup-ui makes, and shows libGDX logo. Any idea of the problem?

Comment: Do you still render the logo somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I render the logo in my render method @Override
 public void render() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  batch.begin();
  sprite.draw(batch);
  batch.end();
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from your comment:

```
@Override public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

The problem is that you clear the color, then check the input (and make a screenshot) and then render the logo.

Move the `controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());` at the end of your `render` method, *after* you rendered the logo (`batch.end()`).